# Batch file to rename based on size on disk

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I was going to make a batch script to share for ex-Dropbox account holders that will go through and rename a file OR folder if the size on disk is > 1 byte.
Using other forums I've managed to come up with the below.

```bash
@ECHO OFF
setlocal
set maxbytesize=1
FOR /F %%i IN ('PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "FileSizeOnDisk.ps1" "E:\Desktop\Folder"') DO set SizeonDisk=%%i AND if %SizeonDisk% LSS %maxbytesize% (ren *.* *.*-DELETED)
EXIT
```

I just need help to loop the powershell command for every file, folder and files in a folder. I don't know how to properly place 2 commands after a DO and can't figure out the code to get it to work on multiple files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "delims=" %%o in ('dir /b /a-d "nameofdirectorytoscan\filemask"') do 
 FOR /F %%i IN ('PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "FileSizeOnDisk.ps1" "nameofdirectorytoscan\%%o"') DO set "Jumba#%%o=%%i"
set size#
pause
```

The result is a set of variables named `Jumba#nameoffile` with values of filesize as returned from Powersmell.

You can then scan the list using

```
for /f "tokens=2,3delims=#=" %%b in ('set Jumba#') do echo name=%%b, size=%%c
```

Comment: How would I insert in my rename command to run on each file?  
`IF %%c LSS %maxbytesize% DO FOR /F %%b (ren *.* *.*-DELETED)`

Comment: In place of `echo name=%%b, size=%%c`, try `IF %%c LSS %maxbytesize% ren "nameofdirectorytoscan\%%b" "%%b-DELETED"` **Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

Comment: Works perfectly thank you!
Only issue I found in testing seems to be that a file LESS then 540 bytes has an on disk size of 0 bytes. Which I didn't realize.
It should be fine, I'll just add an AND IF SIZE <539 bytes.
Thank you very muchly sir.